How to connect to a proxy contract with Typechain?
I'm currently using the ERC20 contract available from OpenZeppelin to generate the typechains.
Now, one of the ERC20 I wish to use is USDC.
USDC is a proxy contract.
How can I connect the typechain ERC20__factory to the implementation instead of the proxy?
If I try to do:
const usdc = ERC20__factory.connect("0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48");
const symbol = await usdc.symbol();
console.log("symbol", symbol);

It is failing on the second line with the error Error: contract runner does not support calling (operation="call", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.2)

This issue "contract runner does not support calling" means ERC20__factory is missing runner/signer/wallet which is used to execute the function call.
You can take a look inside ERC20__factory:
  static connect(address: string, runner?: ContractRunner | null)

I'm using ethers@6 in hardhat console. So the code should be:
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
const runner = wallet.connect(ethers.provider)
const usdc = ERC20__factory.connect("0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48", runner);
const symbol = await usdc.symbol();
console.log("symbol", symbol);


You were right. It was a silly mistake from my part. Thanks!
